# Able to unlock BitLocker drive, but unable to obtain the 48-digit recovery key

Tags: windows-10, encryption, data-recovery, bitlocker, tpm

I'm trying to obtain the 48-digit BitLocker recovery key from a failed drive. Here's what happened:

1. Windows 10 Professional was installed on a Samsung 980 Pro 2TB drive. The login was a local user account with no password. No Microsoft account was used.
2. Bitlocker was enabled. The computer after power on goes to the Windows desktop with no user input required (and with the drive unlocked).
3. Samsung 980 Pro 2TB drive fails due to bug in firmware 3B2QGXA7. The drive is in permanent read-only mode, with most of the data still intact.
4. Due to the read-only mode, Windows cannot boot normally. Windows also cannot enter recovery mode.
5. I used Clonezilla to make a disk image of the failed drive for future recovery.
6. I used Clonezilla to copy the entire Samsung drive onto a known good drive. Windows on Good drive still cannot boot normally. Windows on Good drive can now enter recovery mode with an admin command prompt.
7. Now I can try to obtain the 48-digit BitLocker recovery key via the command prompt. `manage-bde -status` returns:

```
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.19041
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

BitLocker Driver Encryption:
Volume C: []
[Data Volume]

    Size:                 1760.45 GB
    BitLocker Version:    2.0
    Conversion Status:    Used Space Only Encrypted
    Percentage Encrypted: 100.0%
    Encryption Method:    XTS-AES 128
    Protection Status:    Protection Off
    Lock Status:          Unlocked
    Identification Field: Unknown
    Automatic Unlock:     Disabled
    Key Protectors:         None Found
```

8. `manage-bde -protectors C: -get` returns:

```
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.19041
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Volume C: []
All Key Protectors

ERROR: No key protectors found.
```

Here's where I'm stuck. In normal situations, `manage-bde -protectors C: -get` would return the 48-digit recovery key. But in my case it says `No key protectors found`.

Comment: If your computer can hold two disks, try to get the key from the old disk rather than from its copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`No key protectors found` means the disk encryption key is currently stored *unprotected* on the disk. In other words, although the disk is technically encrypted, BitLocker is still in a "permanently unlocked" mode and there is nothing that would need to be recovered yet.

At this point you can either *add* the standard protectors using `-protectors -add -?`, or disable BitLocker and decrypt the disk outright, or just carry on with your regular data recovery process.

Comment: I'm going to `[citation needed]` that one.

Comment: Thank you! Which protector would you suggest? I tried `manage-bde –protectors –add C: -RecoveryPassword` but it failed with `ERROR (code 0x80310053) BitLocker Drive Encryption can only be used for limited provisioning or recovery purposes when the computer is running in pre-installation or recovery environments.`

Comment: @u1686_grawity The current command prompt in recovery mode is extremely limiting. Would it be possible to mount the Good copy drive on a fully working Windows 11 computer and perform the key extraction there?

Comment: Ah, right, you're doing this from a recovery boot; I thought it was able to configure BitLocker but I guess it isn't. But what do you need the key extraction for? The disk already doesn't require a key to begin with.

Comment: Currently if I mount the drive on an Ubuntu system, when I try to mount it, an error pops up saying that it's BitLocker encrypted and a password is required. A password that I don't have (the failed system didn't require a password). My goal is to obtain the recovery key such that this drive can be read in all OSes.

Comment: Is my only option to decrypt the drive using the failed Windows installation and backup the files after the decryption? I'm not keen on doing this because Samsung 980 Pro failing left the entire drive in an unknown state, I don't trust this the OS in this unknown state to decrypt itself. I'd much have a known good OS decrypt the drive using the recovery key.

Comment: I see, I guess that means cryptsetup on Ubuntu probably doesn't understand the concept of "encrypted but inactive" BitLocker yet. In that case you'll need to go through the full Windows installation to add some protectors (the point being that currently the disk has _no_ keys at all, so there's nothing to "extract" yet – you'd be _creating_ a recovery key). But a "recovery key" isn't the only way to decrypt a disk – it would be easier to add a plain old "password" protector instead. (A recovery key is kind of a secondary protector, after all.)

Comment: Thanks again. What I don't understand is that Recovery mode is clearly able to unlock the drive (without a password), so the AES description key is clearly somewhere on the disk, and somewhere in memory. If I could just get this key then I'd be able to read the drive freely, from anywhere.

Comment: It is on disk, yes, and you can dump it with Dislocker or libBDE (or _maybe_ cryptsetup bitlkDump? Crypsetup's Bitlocker support is a very new implementation and doesn't support all the edge cases yet), but the issue is that _neither Windows nor Ubuntu_ would accept it as any input – the tools expect to prompt you for one of the _protector_ keys, but the recovery key is **not the same thing** as the disk's AES key at all. (It's a key that would encrypt a copy of the disk's main AES key.)

Comment: It's all good now. `manage-bde –protectors –add C: -RecoveryPassword` was exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!